# Need help! Replace the “while” loop with a “for” loop

Tags: java

I need replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop. Make sure it produces the same output, if 6 is given as a parameter: `java PowersOfTwo 6`.
But my answer cannot run well. Always outputs:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Below is the previous example:

```
public class PowersOfTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // last power of two to print
        int i = 0; // loop control counter
        int v = 1; // current power of two
        while (i <= N) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + v);
            i = i + 1;
            v = 2 * v;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my answer:

```
public class PowersOfTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // last power of two to print
        int v = 1; // current power of two
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i ++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + v);    
            i = i + 1;
            v = 2 * v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to run it from a command line to pass that argument.

Comment: Try removing `i = i + 1` from inside of `for` body and see if it works. It overflows because you incrementing index twice.

Comment: did you pass args to your program when you ran it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `i = i + 1` inside the loop which is not necessary here since its already done by the for loop

You can fix it this way:

```
public class PowersOfTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // last power of two to print
        int v = 1; // current power of two
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i ++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + v);    
            //i = i + 1; // you dont need this line
            v = 2 * v;
        }
    }
}
```

Or this way:

```
public class PowersOfTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // last power of two to print
        int v = 1; // current power of two
        for (int i = 0; i <= N;) { //no need to i++
            System.out.println(i + " " + v);    
            i = i + 1; 
            v = 2 * v;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you to use a tool like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) - it helps in the majority of cases similar to yours.

*java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0* occurs when trying to iterate an empty array - so check if you pass the params into app properly and didn't forget **6** here:

```
 java PowersOfTwo 6
```

Also I suppose you should remove the *i = i + 1;* line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `,` to separate multiple variables (and increment commands). So you could do something like,

```
for (int i = 0, v = 1; i <= N; i++, v *= 2) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + v);
}
```

Finally, when you run the program, pass the value `N`.

```
java -cp . PowersOfTwo 4
```

Which outputs

```
0 1
1 2
2 4
3 8
4 16
```

For the same result you *could* eliminate `v`, and bitshift `1` left by `i` like

```
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + (1 << i));
}
```